# How to set title in title bar based on which cell is viewed from collectionview cells in xcode ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view

I'm making a medals page for an app I have in mind. I have the app set up in such a way that when a medal is clicked, it will open up a page containing a picture of that medal.

[image]

If possible, I also wish to add in a description for every medal in their view controllers. How do I achieve that?

Here's a sample of the code I have:

Medal.swift

```
import UIKit

class Medals: UICollectionViewController

{

    // Defining the array
    let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "1"), UIImage(named: "2")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //Allows you to populate the cells you've created
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // cell was from the identifier we named earlier

        // we let collectionviewcell handle the connection to UIcollectionviewcell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]


        return cell

    }

    // How many cells do we want to have inside the collection view? Just count the number of images assigned
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imageArray.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showImage"
        {
            let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
            let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath

            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MedalDetail
            vc.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]!
        }
    }

}
```

CollectionViewCell.swift

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


}
```

medaldetails.swift

```
import UIKit

class MedalDetail: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var setTitle: UINavigationItem!

    var image = UIImage()
    var medalTitle = UINavigationItem()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.imageView.image = self.image
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Thanks for you help

edit:

This is how I want the medal page to look like when clicked: 
[image]

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I want to add a description for every medal and a custom title on the nav bar for every medal as well.

Comment: Put a description to where? Be specific. You can show us how you want your UI to look like.

Comment: Edited, notice the change in title name and the addition of some description beneath the icon

Answer (score 0):

First create array of `medalDescriptions` in Medals ViewController then in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` call performSegue to MedalDetail viewController

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let index = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueMedalDetail", sender: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueChallenge" {

        let medalDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MedalDetail
        medalDetailViewController.medalDescription = medalDescriptions[index]
    }
}
```

In MedalDetail create `medalDescription` and in the same viewController change navbar title

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.title = medalDescription

    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let attributes = [
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(),
        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 50)!
    ]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes

}
```

***For future do not name your controllers or other class with just their names add also ViewController or View at the end. For example, MedalDetailViewController. That would be better to understand and read***

Comment: Hi, what I intend to do is for the title bar in medal detail view controller to be set according to the name of the image displayed in it.

Comment: You mean title of the image?

Comment: Yes title of the image

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found another way to do it. I instantiated separate view controller for each medal and thus I can have diffwrent properties per view controller.